# how do i get acceleration out of pygame.event.get()?

Tags: python, pygame

i start pygame and i'm facing a problem.
my code is :

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
  print(event)
```

and i got this

```
<Event(4-MouseMotion {'rel': (1, 0), 'buttons': (0, 0, 0), 'pos': (92, 366)})>
```

can some one let me know how can i got the two number (1, 0) after the rel ?
i tried:

```
real = event.rel
x = real[0]
y = real[1]
```

i just want the number after rel, and it shouldn't be too hard but i can't get it.

Btw i forgot to say... my problem is, it keeps telling me

```
AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'rel'
```

Comment: and it keeps telling me 
AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'rel'

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you do not check the type of the events. Not every event has all possible properties. Only the `MOUSEMOTION` and the `JOYBALLMOTION` events have the `rel` property.

For a full list, see the [documentation](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html).

Your code should look like this:

```
for e in  pygame.event.get():
    # check the type of the event before accessing .rel
    # otherwise an exception will be raised
    if e.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
        x, y = e.rel
        # now do something with x and y
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'rel'

Comment: @Stv Exactly... That's what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Stv, sloth has shown why you are recieving your attribute error, and how you can solve it. give it a shot

Answer (score -1):

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:  # check for mousemotion event
    if event.buttons[0]: # check for left button down
        if event.rel[1] >0 (or whatever) : #  get the rel[1]
```

You can use `event.rel[0]` or `event.rel[1]` to acccess them.

Comment: AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'rel'